# PHP video play on iPad

Tags: php, video, playback

So this is my PHP video code
it works in browsers but when I try to get it to play on iPhones and iPads it seems to bring up the play button with x through it.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://cdn.videos.budtraffic.com/sodaradio/J/Jessie%20J%20-%20Laserlight.mp4');
echo $homepage;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry if this seem like a stupid question, but why not just redirect the browser directly to the file? `header('Location: http://blablabla');`

Comment: because that server is our media file and the only IP address able to access it is the IP address from our sodaradio site

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mp4 video won't play in the iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906558/mp4-video-wont-play-in-the-ipad)

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate : the other question is about client side issues, while this question is about server side issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Explanation on Apple Web site](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6)

**Short answer :**

Because iOS device require the server to support byte-ranges request for videos, and your code does not provide that capability.

**Long answer :**

When iOS device make a request for a video, they don't download the whole video. They download only small chunk at a time, to minimize bandwidth usage, and also because the user may want to skip to a later portion of the video without downloading the previous parts. For that purpose, they make byte ranges request. Basically, they tell the server "Hey, give me the portion of the file between the 100th and 200th byte". Byte-range request use the `Range` header, and look like the following

```
GET /myvideo.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Range: bytes=500-999
```

The server must in that case reply with something like that

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 500-999/20000
```

So you will need much more than those four php line to support iOS devices. First you will to parse the `Range` header. This information is available in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']` global var. You will then need to fetch only that portion of the file and send it to the client. You will also need to populate the `Content-Range` header.

Note that the `Content-Range` header include the complete file size, so your code will need to provide that information. Note also that almost every server support that kind of request for static files. If you don't need to do special treatement to the file, a possible option is to copy the file on the public server and let it do the job for you.

**Non related comment**

Take that as constructive criticism, but your code in its current form will bring your server to its knee. You basically *put the whole file in memory* before sending it, and worse, you do it for *every request*. If 100 people download a 100MB video at the same time, you'll need **10 GB** of memory on the server to serve them. That does not scale, not at all.

A much better solution would be to send the file as its read from your CDN, using the [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function. That way, you only need to use a small chunk of memory, and you can serve a lot more concurrent requests.

**EDIT** : actually, you also need to respond with a special response code, the 206 partial content. I forgot that in the first version of this answer. Now fixed

Comment: So would you be able to help or point me in the right direction to where to fix this

Comment: Search for "byte-range php" on google. You should be able to find example of code on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing: a secure PHP script to access MP4 video.

iOS (iPad & iPhone) does not work with it.

I tryed with what you said (byte range), following this tutorial:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/content-delivery-mobile-devices

But iPad NEVER send "HTTP_RANGE" it in its request: cause it's a .php file, why should it do it??

I made a rewrite rule (access.mp4 -> access.php), and even when iOS try to reach access.mp4, there is NO HTTP_RANGE in request to server.

So, I think there is NO WAY to make secure PHP script working with iOS...

Comment: Open a new question and paste the code you use (sanitized for private info of course). Then me or someone else can help you.