# camtasia video NOT playing on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, video, mp4, camtasia

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="CRM.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

Above is the htm5 code being used for the playing of an mp4, yet it won't play in iPad. Any ideas?

Comment: checkout this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906558/mp4-video-wont-play-in-the-ipad

Answer (score 1):

A QuickTime file should work on your iPad. So when in Camtasia (or at least in Camtasia 2 on the tabs above).

Share->Advanced Export

AT the bottom there is a dropbox of files you can export to.

-> Export to QuickTime Movie.

Hope this helps!!